# JMeter - In Test Plan that executes consequtive Thread Groups - How to execute particular Thread Group only once

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I have a Test Plan, that executes multiple Thread Groups consequtevly - But for one of these Thread Groups I want to be executed once and on next Test Plan exection it should be ommited. Is this possible?

Comment: Execute once a day? Once only and never use again? Can you give example of usage

Comment: Once only and never execute again. Is it possible to set up like this in automated manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it as follows:

1. Put all the requests in your Thread Group under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) and use the following expression as the "Condition"

   ```
   ${__groovy(!new File('somefile').exists(),)}
   ```
2. Add a [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) at the end of your Thread Group and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new File('somefile').createNewFile()
   ```

   - If Controller checks for `somefile` file presence in JMeter's "bin" folder (or whatever is your current working directory) and if there is no file in it - its children will be executed.
   - JSR223 Sampler creates this `somefile` when it's being executed so next time you will run your test the condition will not be met and Thread Group will skip all its samplers. If you will need to re-enable the Thread Group - just delete this `somefile`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understood your requirement. If you would like to ignore a specific thread group dynamically , then you could pass the 'number of threads/users' for the thread group to 0 using properties.

more information is here - http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-manage-test-plan/